# Timeout subprocess pid

Tags: shell-script, timeout

I'm using the `timeout` utility inside a bash script to run a command for a given time (e.g., `timeout -s SIGINT 500s ./my_script`).
I want to monitor the process `myscript` to see how much CPU/memory it uses (e.g. with the `htop -p <pid>` command).

I know that when a process is started in background (with `&`) I can get its pid programmatically by retrieving the `$!` variable. The problem is that timeout spawns a new subprocess and with the `$!` variable I get the "pid of timeout" and not the pid of myscript.

How can you retrive the pid of the subprocess spawned by timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `timeout` a chance to start the script, then ask `ps` for the process whose parent is `timeout`:

```
timeout -s SIGINT 500s ./my_script &
bgpid=$!
sleep 1
p=$(ps -o pid= --ppid "$bgpid")
echo The pid you want is: "$p"
```